# SignalR - Sending from server-to-client from latest Hub context

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have a simple demo with only 1 client and the server. I can send messages back and forth, very trivial stuff.

The server Hub has a timer which sends a message to the client(s) every 1000 milliseconds. Now I have a button, where when clicked, sends a message to the server (via signalR).

Problem:
When the button is clicked (and the message sent to the server), the Hub is instantiated each time (I read about the SignalR lifecycle [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubclass)).
Of course, when the Hub is instantiated the Timer is also instantiated. So the side effect (ie. bug) that I am seeing is that messages are being send to the client from multiple Hub instances.

What I would like:
I would like the client to receive messages (from the Timer that is running on the Hub), but only 1 set of messages from a single Hub (latest Hub instance?). I do not want simultaneous/multiple messages that were spawned from each Hub that was instantiated.

But perhaps I am doing something drastically wrong in design here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn´t set the timer in the hub instance because they are re-created on every request.
Just create a Singleton class to handle the timer and actions. Then access that singleton from your hub instance.

The singleton instance will persist during the whole live cycle of your application, thus you will create only one timer.
To avoid concurrency problems, your singleton should be [Lazy](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/05/19/c-system.lazylttgt-and-the-singleton-design-pattern.aspx)

Comment: Note that this is different for Core: "In ASP.NET Core SignalR, the connection model has been simplified. Connections are made directly to a single hub, rather than a single connection being used to share access to multiple hubs." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.1